# making multi-index in pandas dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set where there is a matrix of numeric values indexed by a time variable. Each matrix is a numpy array (that can be converted into a dataframe with columns corresponding to columns of the matrix). if i have these matrices how can i make them into a single dataframe where each matrix has a time index? specifically:

```
# time t1
d1 = pandas.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4], "b":[10,20,30,40]})
# time t2
d2 = pandas.DataFrame({"a": [10,20,30,40], "b": [1,2,5,6]})
# time t3 
d3 = ...
```

i want to make an index called "time" to index these dataframes, and then aggregate values from columns "a" and "b" across the time index. how can you do this in pandas?

my attempt:

```
d=pandas.DataFrame([d1,d2],index=(0, 1),columns=["time"])
```

*update*: unutbu's solution for adding two hierarchical columns is:

`c = pd.concat([d1, d2], keys=[('t1', 'p1'), ('t2', 'p2')], names=['time', 'position'])`

my final question is how do you access this resulting structure? for example how do you do vectorized operations across `time`, or across `position`? eg take the average of the rows for each value of `time`.

also, how does this compare to encoding `time` and `position` into each dataframe and using `groupby`? in other words when to use levels versus flat columns that are grouped? here's an alternative solution using flat dataframe with groupby:

```
d1["time"] = 1
d1["position"] = "x"
d2["time"] = 2
d2["position"] = "y"
c = pandas.concat([d1, d2])
# take mean for all time values
c.groupby("time").apply(lambda x: np.mean(x, axis=1))
```

Comment: @VidhyaG: it makes perfect sense to refer to an answer and to elaborate on a question. it's done frequently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4], "b":[10,20,30,40]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [10,20,30,40], "b": [1,2,5,6]})
```

then [`pd.concat([d1, d2], keys=['t1', 't2'])`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) returns:

```
In [177]: pd.concat([d1, d2], keys=['t1', 't2'])
Out[177]: 
       a   b
t1 0   1  10
   1   2  20
   2   3  30
   3   4  40
t2 0  10   1
   1  20   2
   2  30   5
   3  40   6
```

---

If you wish to add more than one level to the new MultiIndex, you can instead pass a *list of tuples* to the `keys` parameter:

```
In [237]: pd.concat([d1, d2], keys=[('t1', 'p1'), ('t2', 'p2')], names=['time', 'position'])
Out[237]: 
                  a   b
time position          
t1   p1       0   1  10
              1   2  20
              2   3  30
              3   4  40
t2   p2       0  10   1
              1  20   2
              2  30   5
              3  40   6
```

Note, it is important here that `keys` receives a list of **tuples**, rather than a list of lists.

Comment: does this use multiindex under the hood? also this doesn't capture the fact that my indices are ordered. t1, t2, are numeric and ordered and the dictionary loses this...

Comment: `pd.concat(..., keys=...)` returns a DataFrame with a multiindex. By passing the time values (numeric or otherwise) as a list to the `keys` parameter, the order of the indices will be maintained.

Comment: and how can this be done with two indices? say i wanted have 'time' and also 'position'? this does not work: ```pd.concat([d1, d2], keys=[['t1', 't2'], ['p1', 'p2']], names=["time", "position"])```

Comment: the documentation to concat is impenetrable and its hard to find examples of this relatively simple task in the docs

Comment: Pass to `keys` a list of tuples, not a list of lists.